# How to improve python download video speed?

Tags: python, web-scraping, download

I want to download video from a website,and here is my code.

Each video is approximately 900MB in size (about 40 minutes).

I am using multi-threading in Python to download the videos, but the download speed has not increased much.

I would like to know if this is normal and if there are any methods to speed up my program.

```
import requests
import concurrent.futures
import json
import time
import random
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()


result_video = []


url = "https://fan-topia.com/api/user/27828/"

urls = [f"{url}video?page={page}" for page in range(1,74)]

header = {'User-Agent': ua.random,
             'cookie':'cookies',
             'referer':'https://fan-topia.com/u/MondoKpop'}

def scrape(urls):
    try:
        req = requests.get(urls,headers=header)
        
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 5))
        
        gj = json.loads(req.text)

        for i in gj['posts']:
            for j in i['attachments']:
                print(j['file_name'],j['url'])
                results = {'title':j['file_name'],'url':j['url']}
                result_video.append(results)

        return result_video
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    
def download_video(result_video):
    r = requests.get(result_video['url'],headers=header,stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(f'D:\\fantopia\\mondoKpop\\test\\{result_video["title"]}','wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)

def line_notify():
    line_headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + "token",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    params = {"message":f"Succeed!"}
    r = requests.post("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify",
                          headers=line_headers, params=params)


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    executor.map(scrape,urls)

time.sleep(30)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=15) as executor:
    executor.map(download_video,result_video)


print(line_notify())
```